# Weigh points toward center more heavily in average.

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Using PIL and Python 2.7.

I had the following code for deciding whether an image was mostly dark or light.

```
def blackWhite(image):
    '''Return `True` if the image is mostly white, else `False`'''
    l=image.convert('L').load()
    w,h=image.size
    lums=sum([[l[x,y] for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],[])
    return sum(lums)/float(len(lums))>127
```

I'm trying to modify this so that points toward the center of the image are weighed more heavily than those on the outside.

So far, I've written this code:

```
def blackWhite(image):
    '''Return `True` if the image is mostly white, else `False` Weigh center pixels more heavily.'''
    def weight(x,y):
        '''Return the weight of the point at (x,y) based on function y = -0.5|x-8|+4'''
        return (-0.5*abs(x-8)+4)*(-0.5*abs(x-8)+4)
    l=image.convert('L').load()
    w,h=image.size
    lums=sum([[l[x,y] for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],[])
    weights=sum([[weight(x,y) for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],[])
    weighted=[x*weights[n] for n,x in enumerate(lums)]
    return (sum(weighted)/float(len(weighted)))/sum(weights)
```

The values this returns are not what I expect, I expected values out of 255. Where is the error in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't have the formula right. The last line should not divide by the length of weighted and THEN the sum of weights, it should only divide by the sum of weights.

```
return sum(weighted)/sum(weights)
```